# Declaring a vector of pointers to vector of strings

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, stdvector

I have a 2D table of strings (using STL vector) and am trying to modify so that the table is a vector of pointers to vectors of strings. I know that this will require changing the constructor so that rows are created dynamically, and pointers to the rows are inserted into the table, but I'm not sure how to go about creating this table in the first place.

In my .h file:

```
class StringTable
{
public:

    StringTable(ifstream & infile);

    // 'rows' returns the number of rows
    int rows() const;

    // operator [] returns row at index 'i';
    const vector<string> & operator[](int i) const;

private:
    vector<vector<string> >  table;

};
```

In my .cpp file:

```
StringTable::StringTable(ifstream & infile)
{
    string          s;
    vector<string>  row;

    while (readMultiWord(s, infile))  // not end of file
    {
        row.clear();
        do
        {
            row.push_back(s);
        }
        while (readMultiWord(s, infile));
        table.push_back(row);
    }
}

int StringTable::rows() const
{
    return table.size();
}

const vector<string> & StringTable::operator[](int i) const
{
    return table[i];
}
```

I feel like this is probably a pretty easy switch, but I don't have a lot of experience using vectors, and I'm not sure where to start. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want a vector of pointers? That sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @BrendanLong It's C/C++!

Comment: Why do you have a `while (readMultiWord(s, infile))` inside of a `while (readMultiWord(s, infile))`? Does it return `false` at the end of a row, or something?

Comment: @muntoo Yes, it reads strings from a table in which each field is separated by s. When the program reads in a word, it pushes back s, and then when it hits the end of a line, it pushes the row of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create some form of multidimensional vector. Have you considered using boost? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: If you really want to roll your own, Effective C++ by Meyers covers this exact scenario. TLDR: rather than hacking things with operator[], just create a function "string getElement(int row, int col)" and "setElement(int row, int col, const string &value);"

Answer (score -1):

OK the easiest way to do this is with typedef. Also it seems that you are using 'using' clauses in you header files - you should never ever do this.

```
class StringTable
{
    public:
         typedef std::vector<std::string> Strings_t;
         std::vector<Strings_t *> table;
};
```

Dont forget when adding a now you will need to allocate memory ie:

```
StringTable tbl;
StringTable::Strings_t *data_ptr=new StringTable::Strings_t;

data_ptr->push_back("foo");
data_ptr->push_back("bar");

tbl.table.push_back(data_ptr);
```

[Corrected]

Comment: How does a `typedef` make this more clear? Even in your trivial example it's causing problems (`Strings_t` vs `String_t`).

Comment: Yeah, @Paul, don't use `using namespace std;` inside your header files... Actually, I wouldn't use it *anywhere*.

Comment: @Brendan - a) I should have compiled (String_t vs Strings_t) is a typo and also I forgot class namespace

Comment: Why are you using `new`? That's just asking for a memory leak. And if you really want to use pointers for no reason, fix this line `tbl.table.push_back(&data_ptr);` and use `delete dataptr;`.

Comment: Using new is perfectly fine - it is NOT asking for a memory leak - and it is a massive performance increase. Please dont avoid language features because you are scared of them - use them properly and they work fine.